# Null pointer exception when setting values to TextView in Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I have two fragments in my mainactivity, from the first one, the user clicks on a button and send through my listener a char to the second fragment, depends of that char a textview in the second fragment must print a text. But in my metho onActivityCreated my textview is always null.

This is my code:
FragmentOne

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    btnChefcito = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.btnChefcito);
    btnChefcita = (Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.btnChefcita);

    btnChefcito.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            welcomeListener.elegirSexo(sexo);
            replaceFragment();
        }
    });

    btnChefcita.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sexo="f";
            welcomeListener.elegirSexo(sexo);
            replaceFragment();
        }
    });
}
```

This is my second fragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    tviBienvenida = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tviBienvenida);
}



public void getSex(String sex){
    if(sex.equals("m")){
        tviBienvenida.setText(bienvenido);
    }else if(sex.equals("f")){
        tviBienvenida.setText(bienvenida);
    }
}
```

Comment: where you initialized `tviBienvenida`  ?

Comment: in the method onActivityCreated but there is a nullpointer in tviBienvenida.setText

Comment: instead of doing stuff in onActivityCreated, try doing in onCreateView()

Comment: onCreateView method by its name is justifying that it will be called when there is a view in it, the reason you getting null textView is because you trying to work with the TextView while there is no View Actually

Comment: I am now trying to do everything in onCreateView but follows the same mistake the about NullPointer in my textview!

Comment: inflater.inflate(R.layout.YourFragmentLayout, container, false); In here you giving your Fragment's layout right ? Textview is present in that Fragment's xml layout ?

Comment: Yes, I checked that too

Comment: where are you calling this method getSex(String sex) ?

Comment: For me you are not calling this method so how can Textview have any value ?

Comment: Can you see my code? I dont know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing in `onActivityCreated` Do This in `onCreateView`:

```
private static View viewHolder;

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        viewHolder = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YourFragmentLayout, container, false);

        btnChefcito = (Button) viewHolder.findViewById(R.id.YourButtonId);

btnChefcito.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            welcomeListener.elegirSexo(sexo);
            replaceFragment();
        }
    });


        return viewHolder;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On Android you have to declare a global variable. 
 tviBienvenida in you class, and on create view

```
tviBienvenida = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tviBienvenida);
```

The variable tviBienvenida will always have the value, and any change in tviBienvenida will also be refected to your textview.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_id, null, false);

     btnChefcito = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnChefcito);
btnChefcita = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnChefcita);

btnChefcito.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        welcomeListener.elegirSexo(sexo);
        replaceFragment();
    }
});

btnChefcita.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        sexo="f";
        welcomeListener.elegirSexo(sexo);
        replaceFragment();
    }
});
    return view;

}
```

the problem is public void `onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)` not create any view in fragment so replace all code in this method

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

sorry for my English.

Comment: For some reason you just given the same answer as of mine instead of justifying my answer

Comment: when the second fragment is show getSex() method not called . there many way to parse data one fragment to another fragment you can use this library https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Answer (score 0):

Implement view in onCreateView method and repleace your stuff there, for example:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);

        //your code

        return view;
}
```